# How to alert data inside variable

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I need to alert this data (Status):

```
string Status = RFCGridView.DataKeys[selectedIndex].Values[1].ToString();
```

i have tried using this script:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, GetType(), "alertMessage", @"alert(Status)", true);
```

and it does not working.

even when i do :

```
String a = "hi";
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, GetType(),
"alertMessage", @"alert(a)", true);
```

it didnt work.

Please help me, experts!

Comment: Does the alert come up in the source in your HTML page?

Comment: @"alert("+Status+")"  try this

Comment: Patrick, No. I just want to alert if the data i retrieve is the right one

Comment: Vikas, it isnt working...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use the following code in you button (or whatever control do you use) handler:

```
public partial class MyPage : Page
{
    protected void Button1_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ShowMessage("Hello World!");
    }

    public void ShowMessage(string message)
    {
        var script = $@"<script type='text/javascript'>window.onload=function(){{alert('{message}')}};</script>";
        ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(GetType(), "alert", script);
    }
}
```